# get the highest key (alphabetically) from object javascript

Tags: javascript, object, key, alphabetical

Suppose I have the following object:

```
company: {price:{"20200511": "6.15", "20200602": "6.12", "20200610": "6.15"}}
```

is there an easy trick to retrieve the price of the most recent date, *without knowing what the most recent date within that object actually is*?

Note: the dates can be sorted alphabetically.

I could retrieve it by looping over it, i wonder if there is an easier way though.

Comment: An object is probably the wrong structure if you need something like "most recent entry". Objects are sorted by key and there may be order guarantees depending on your browser/version, but that's it. How about an array sorted by date?

Comment: I agree, a map/object is the wrong structure for this. Try an array, and enforce that new items always be inserted into the correct order when they are added. Then you are guaranteed that the item at the beginning (or end, depending on how you order) will be the most recent.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer :

```
Object.keys(company['price']).sort(function (a, b) {
    return b - a;
  })[0]
```